# how to find ODBC driver name?

Tags: php, sql, odbc

I am using `PHP 5.5` and `ODBC` installed and active but still I have that error I couldn't connect the server. I Guess I need odbc driver name.

```
$conn = "DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=$server;DATABASE=$db";
```

> Warning: odbc_connect(): SQL error: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified, SQL state IM002 in SQLConnect in

Answer (score 0):

You can be using PDO to connect. If you are on windows:

```
$this->stmt = new PDO ("sqlsrv:server=$server;Database=$database;",$user,$pass);
```

On Linux:

```
$this->stmt = new PDO ("dblib:host=$server;dbname=$database;charset=UTF-8;",$user,$pass);
```

Comment: I'm using a linux server.

Comment: So try the second option, you will probably need to install dblib, if you are using Ubuntu Server you can run sudo apt-get install php5-sybase

Comment: Hey, I am on redhat 7.4, php 5.4 I am having the same issue.. any resolution on this?

PHP Warning:  odbc_connect(): SQL error: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL Server Native Client 10.0' : file not found, SQL state 01000 in SQLConnect in on line